# Python Opencv imshow error

Tags: python, opencv

my code:

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread("dU4fHDw-Ho.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

cv2.imshow('image', img)
k = cv2.waitKey(0)
if k == 27:
    cv2.destroyWindow()
```

And i get this error:

```
OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script) in cvShowImage, file /io/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp, line 583
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "simpleopencv.py", line 4, in <module>
    cv2.imshow('image', img)
cv2.error: /io/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:583: error: (-2) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function cvShowImage
```

I'm using linux mint KDE
What might be the problem?

**Update1: Opencv works fine with python2.7 but not working for python3.5**

**Update2: As it turns out running the [script](https://github.com/milq/milq/blob/master/scripts/bash/install-opencv.sh) as Jack Gold suggested actually worked but since i already had *cv2* folder in my */usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/ (which was installed using PIP i think)* conflicted with the one install using the script and python3 kept using the PIP version so, I deleted that *cv2* folder and restarted and everything worked fine.**

Comment: You're missing some libraries, please refer to my answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/44263478/7220609

Comment: i stil get the same error

Comment: well, actually it did fixed it, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Nothing to worry buddy,I suffered the same and this is how I got rid of this error, see if you have installed opencv via pip or pip3 or apt-get, first you gotta uninstall it

```
sudo pip3 uninstall (what you wrote while installing)

or sudo pip uninstall (what you wrote while installing)

or sudo apt-get remove (what you wrote while installing)
```

and afterwards **build the opencv package from source code from github.**

```
git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git

cd ~/opencv

mkdir release

cd release

cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ..

make

sudo make install
```

This will solve the problem. All the best.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the problem since it works fine for me. But just as an alternative, use plt.imshow() from Matplotlib, it also works fine.

Comment: just tried, but matplotlib's image is quite different than opencv's(using python 2.7). It's  displaying grayscale image but matplotlibs's image looks green

Comment: plt.imshow() also accepts another parameter "cmap", try plt.imshow(img, cmap="gray") to show image in gray scale

Comment: does that means I don't have to pass cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE in cv2.imread() ?

Comment: Yes, it can take an array of shape (n, m, 3) and show it in gray scale.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install OpenCV using pip? If you did, note that as mentioned [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/opencv-python), this is the unofficial package for OpenCV and does not have support for GUI windows (`cv2.imshow()`, etc)

I would recommend using Anaconda to install opencv using `conda install -c conda-forge opencv=3.2.0` or `conda install -c menpo opencv3=3.2.0`

Answer (score 0):

Easier solution is provided by conda

> conda install -c loopbio -c conda-forge -c pkgw-forge ffmpeg-feature ffmpeg gtk2 opencv

You may see the following error after conda install

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "./test.py", line 21, in <module>
      import cv2
ImportError: libopenblas.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Just install openblas library would solve

> yum install openblas-devel -y

Reference

[sdvillal | github] https://github.com/conda-forge/opencv-feedstock/issues/43

Answer (score 0):

You should use absolute path to read your image.

For me on Mac OS:

```
img = cv2.imread('/Users/nicholasleung/Documents/after effect/AL.png')
```